# How to run Ansible playbook tasks in order of tags

Tags: ansible

I want to run tasks in ansible playbook in order of tags given in --tags

My ansible playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    file_path: '{{filename}}'
  tasks:
    - name: Delete user
      user:
        name: "{{username}}"
        state: absent
        remove: yes
      tags:
        - delete_user

    - name: Create user
      user: 
        name: "{{username}}"
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: "{{groupname}}"
        password: "{{ password |password_hash('sha512') }}"
      tags:
        - create_user

    - name: Add ssh key
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{username}}"
        key: "{{lookup('file', 'file_path')}}"
        exclusive: yes
      tags:
        - add_ssh_key
```

Run Ansible

```
ansible-playbook createuser.yml --extra-vars "username=hello password=helloworld groupname=something filename=/path/to/filename" --tags=create_user,add_ssh_key,delete_user
```

Expected Output

```
TASK: [Create user] *********************************************************** 
changed: [ip address]

TASK: [Add ssh key] *********************************************************** 
changed: [ip address]

TASK: [Delete user] *********************************************************** 
ok: [ip address]
```

Output Comes

```
TASK: [Delete user] *********************************************************** 
ok: [ip address]

TASK: [Create user] *********************************************************** 
changed: [ip address]

TASK: [Add ssh key] *********************************************************** 
changed: [ip address]
```

**Order of tags given**

create_user,add_ssh_key,delete_user

**But Executed in order**

delete_user,create_user,add_ssh_key,

Answer (score 8):

That's not what tags are for and there is no way to do that within Ansible. Task are always executed in the order they have been defined in the tasks file(s) and/or in order roles have been added to a playbook/play.

If you want to target specific tasks in order you could call the playbook multiple times with a single tag applied.

```
ansible-playbook ... --tags=create_user
ansible-playbook ... --tags=add_ssh_key
ansible-playbook ... --tags=delete_user
```

You could write a simple bash script to automate that. (That's what one usually ends up with anyway when you have a more complex setup and have to deal with multiple tags)

Comment: i agree , ansible tag runs a specific part of the configuration without running the whole playbook.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, all tasks are executed in the order they are in the playbook if no tags are given. I think because your tags cover all tasks in the playbook, they are just executed in the order as they would without any tags. So, a solution could be to rearrange the tasks in the playbook.

Example playbook:

```
  - hosts: localhost

    tasks:
      - name: Third task
        shell:
        tags: "third"

      - name: Second task
        shell:
        tags: "second"

      - name: First task
        shell:
        tags: "first"
```

First run:

```
ansible-playbook -c 'local' test.yml --tags=first,second,third --list-tasks
```

Output:

```
playbook: test.yml

play #1 (localhost): localhost        TAGS: []
  tasks:
    Third task        TAGS: [third]
    Second task       TAGS: [second]
    First task        TAGS: [first]
```

Second run:

```
ansible-playbook -c 'local' test.yml --tags=third,first,second --list-tasks
```

Output(didn't change):

```
playbook: test.yml

play #1 (localhost): localhost        TAGS: []
  tasks:
    Third task        TAGS: [third]
    Second task       TAGS: [second]
    First task        TAGS: [first]
```

Now let's rearrange tasks in the playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: First task
      shell:
      tags: "first"

    - name: Second task
      shell:
      tags: "second"

    - name: Third task
      shell:
      tags: "third"
```

Final run:

```
ansible-playbook -c 'local' test.yml --tags=third,first,second --list-tasks
```

Output (proper order):

```
playbook: test.yml

play #1 (localhost): localhost        TAGS: []
  tasks:
    First task        TAGS: [first]
    Second task       TAGS: [second]
    Third task        TAGS: [third]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Generally, all tasks are executed in the order they are in the playbook if no tags are given.

Now tasks are executed in ALPHABETICAL order in my environment. (ansible 2.6.0, not latest)

I have two answers:

1. Call the playbook multiple times with a single tag
2. Set up the tasks with `wait_for` ([doc here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html)) so that the second task waits until a file (or something) exists that the first task delivers.

Comment: That should only be the case if you use the `order: "sorted"` option. See [Ordering execution based on inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory)